# C# Find and replace data inside XML tag

Tags: c#, xml

**Xml File :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<ResDoc>
<Summary>
My name is Magesh
</Summary>
</ResDoc>
```

How to find the data "Magesh" inside Summary tag and replace it as "GivenName".

A c# code to load XML file, find and replace.

I have tried to loading xml file using XMLDocument, find and replace. But it is not expected.

```
xdoc = new XmlDocument {PreserveWhitespace = true};
xdoc.LoadXml(taggedresume);
string Name1 = "Magesh";

foreach (XmlNode var in xdoc.SelectSingleNode("//ResDoc/summary"))
{
 var.InnerXml.Replace(Name1, "GivenName");                   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string xml = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""iso-8859-1""?>
<ResDoc>
<Summary>
My name is Magesh
</Summary>
</ResDoc>";

        XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

        var element = doc.Element("ResDoc").Element("Summary");

        element.Value = element.Value.Replace("Magesh", "YourName");

        Console.WriteLine(element.Value);
        Console.ReadKey();

    }
```

Here an example, next time try something by yourself first. You need to have reference to `System.Xml.Linq;`

Comment: Thanks @mybirthname. I have tried using xmldocument, but it is not as expected. Could you find solution.